# Where are Azure Data Lake Analytics databases stored?

Tags: azure, hadoop, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I created a database with some tables through a U-SQL script run through the Azure Data Lake Tools for Visual Studio (see screenshot below).  Is that database stored in the Data Lake Store?

The file structure as shown in the Azure portal

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the artifacts related to databases are stored in the Azure Data Lake Store. However not all of the artifacts related to databases are stored in the associated ADLS account. More specifically some of the metadata associated with the databases are stored in a ADL service-managed internal location that is not directly accessible to you. What you will see in the ADLS account is the data associated with the tables and databases in an internal format. Hope this information is useful.

Thanks,
Amit

Comment: Is the data stored in the internal location charged at the same rate as the ADLS (i.e. 6 cents per GB)?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Amit's answer:

The data that is stored in the store is stored in the `\catalog` folder of your default ADLS account. It will be charged at the same rate as the remaining data.

The cost of the data that is stored in the internal metadata service is internalized into the ADLA COGS calculations.